# How to inject a specific subclass based on a property value using @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Having an application.yml like the following:

```yaml
tests:
  happy-path:
    - type: single
      other-property: "other-value"
    - type: parallel
      other-property: "another-value"
```

And having a Class like this one, where I have a Lists of Test type:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConstructorBinding
public class TestRunner {
  private List<Test> happyPath;
  
  public TestRunner(List<Test> tests) {
    this.tests = tests;
  }
}
```

Test type has two different subclass implementations, SingleTest and ParallelTest, booth extending Test class.

**Anyone knows how can I tell Spring to inject an instance of `SingleTest` when `tests.happy-path[*].type==single` and inject an instance of `ParallelTest` when `tests.happy-path[*].type==parallel` so I end up with a List of Test that in reality is a List of SingleTest and ParallelTest implementations?**

I've tried with Converters with no luck for now :(